# Windows 10 add custom fonts to command line

Tags: cmd, fonts, windows-10

I'm trying to add fonts to the windows command line so the Ubuntu terminal can use the pre-patched Meslo LG installed from the powerline fonts github page (see below) (so vim-airline won't have any missing special characters).

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

I've followed the tutorial here:

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/

I've installed the fonts successfully, so I can use the font in word.
I've tried different names for the string value and restarted several times but nothing seems to work.

I've look around online, every source offers the same advice for going through the registry editor.

I'm not sure what to do from here and I'd really appreciate some advice.

I'd also really appreciate some insight into how the registry uses the string value to match with the ttf.

**EDIT 1:**

Windows has a linux subsystem which you can run bash or any other terminal emulator on. In Linux you could add whatever type of font you wanted either through the CLI or GUI install.

I wanted to install Meslo LG S for powerline (the vim plugin that gives you a status bar) since patched fonts are needed that support the special characters.

As it turns out, when it comes to fonts, Windows doesn't care what you've specified. Since the terminal emulator is built on top of the cmd executable, it has the same limitations for fonts.

Rather than just moving to some other terminal emulator, I wanted to solve the problem so other people who're having the same issue with ubuntu terminal for windows 10 could get some help.

As it turns out, Meslo is not a monospace font, so it can't be used in cmd.

Knowing this, I simply chose another patched monospace font and everything works fine.

I haven't answered my question yet because I thought maybe someone with a bit more experience with MS-DOS could show an alternative.

Comment: Just don't bother. If a standard mono space font doesn't work, install a different terminal emulator.

Comment: Yes I've tried turning it on and off again

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking about `cmd`, about powershell, or about the linux subsystem `bash`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added some clarification. Hope that helps

Comment: Some more corrections: ms-dos is an old operating system. It has _nothing_ to do with "cmd", which is the "windows console" (as opposed to PowerShell, the other command line interface available by default in Windows). You're right in that only monospace fonts are supported, mostly [for historically sound reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070516-00/?p=26843). But, this is also irrelevant: "bash" is itself just another CLI invocation, you can run it in _any terminal emulator_ so: grab ConEmu, tell it to use Meslo, type `bash`, done?

Comment: An example of the linux subsystem `bash` running in ConEmu, with the font set to the ridiculous "le gourmet", bouncy version: https://i.imgur.com/idfkm3D.png -- you don't need to make `cmd` use a proportional font, you just need to invoke `bash` in a terminal emulator that supports proportional fonts.

Comment: Yes I realise that you can do that in ConEmu (which is what my collegues recommended), however I wanted to figure out why it wouldn't work with the Ubuntu terminal emulator just so I'd know if this ever happens again. I appreciate the advice however :)